# Regular Expression validate URL in perl

Tags: regex, perl, validation

I'm trying to finish up my assignment and only last one is to validate the URL

The requirement is as follow:

url only allows alphanumerical characters and the following  :/.~?=+&    No two periods can exist consecutively.

here is what I have so far but it doesn't work

```
m|(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?|
```

So what happen now that anything I enter it just pass the matching process that I do which is something like this

```
$return = $search =~ m|(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?|;
```

so it always return true for me even I just type nothing in the search box.

Comment: @JackManey What do you mean string doesn't work? I'm saying that when I type something to macth with the regular expression and it just pass the test like always TRUE

Comment: The string literal "doesn't work" is not an error message. Therefore you have to specify what "doesn't work" actually means.

Comment: @JackManey it means it does not work in a way that I want....

Comment: ...and what is that, exactly? **Be specific**. We can't read your mind.

Comment: "does not work in a way that I want" ...which is unspecified.  What is it supposed to do, what does it do, what does the input data look like, what happens when you run it?

Comment: @JackManey Sorry I thought my question was clear already.....

I want to create a regular expression for check the URL the user enter

and the requirement is

url only allows alphanumerical characters and the following :/.~?=+& No two periods can exist consecutively.

Comment: Okay, again, why doesn't it work? Don't just throw up your hands helplessly; **do something**. Explain.

Comment: @JackManey question updated, I'm really sorry.

Comment: Okay, looking at your update, it appears as though your regex matches the empty string, so yes, if nothing is entered as a search term, this regex will match it.

Comment: @JackManey yeah that is why I'm strugling on this because I'm new to this stuff and I'm trying to only allow like what the requirement is.

Comment: Consider using the [`/x` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) on regexes.  It makes it ignore whitespace.  Then you can space out the elements of your regex so its easier to read and understand.  You can also use [`qr//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) to construct smaller regexes, for example make one to match against the scheme part, and build them into a larger one.

Comment: You've never been clear as to what the requirement is. If you want to not match the empty string, then change some of those question marks in your regex.

Comment: @JackManey the requirement say

url only allows alphanumerical characters and the following :/.~?=+& No two periods can exist consecutively.

so I assume the URL can be something like this

`http://mypage.com/~homedirect/index.cgi?thereare=yes&key=value`

Comment: Right, so change some of the question marks in your regex, since they're primarily responsible for allowing a zero-character match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I'm getting from my regex turbulator (soon to be a commercial product)

Without group count

```
 (?:                                                 #(.*))?
      ( [^:/?\#]+ )
      :
 )?
 (?:
      //
      ( [^/?\#]* )
 )?
 ( [^?\#]* )
 (?:
      \?
      ( [^\#]* )
 )?
      (  <-- Unbalanced  '('
      ?:
```

With group count

```
     (?:                                                 #(.*))?
1         ( [^:/?\#]+ )
          :
     )?
     (?:
          //
2         ( [^/?\#]* )
     )?
3    ( [^?\#]* )
     (?:
          \?
4         ( [^\#]* )
     )?
          (  <-- Unbalanced  '('
          ?:
```

Comment: The reason the # comment stayed on the top is the heuristics. Comments stay on the line that originated them and in the same place. Its very usefull, and a long complicated story.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe works as follow:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927730/regular-expression-validate-url-in-perl';
@ds = $url =~ m|(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?|;
print Dumper(\@ds);
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'http',
          'stackoverflow.com',
          '/questions/11927730/regular-expression-validate-url-in-perl',
          undef,
          undef
        ];
```

Comment: You should correct his regex before making improvements. ie;  show him where he is wrong first.